# Firefox add-on to move the tab bar

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, browser-tabs

EDIT: *I'm using firefox 4.0 beta to achieve this. It doesn't let me move tab bar, but it lets me move other stuff onto the tab bar, which is basically the same.*

Hi, I'm using Firefox on my netbook, and I want to save as many vertical pixels as possible without turning to full-screen mode. Right now, the only thing in my way is the fact that the tab bar can't be moved like the navigation bar or the bookmarks toolbar. I'm looking for a Firefox add-on that will let me place the tab bar side-by-side with the other bars.

CLARIFICATION: I do not want to make the tab bar vertical. I want it to keep it horizontal. An example: if you right-click an empty space in the navigation toolbar and then click "Customize", you can drag the bookmarks toolbar and place it side-by-side with the navigation toolbar. That's want to do with the tab bar. I'd like to place it right beside the navigation bar.

Is there an add-on for that? (the lighter the better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [**Hide Tabbar**](https://addons.mozilla.org/sl/firefox/addon/12716/) addon -- will move it away from visibility...

> Hide the tabbar by just pressing a key.

---

Tab Mix Plus also has a 'Always' hide option, but I couldn't find an easy way to toggle the tabbar. Would be good if that can be done -- can save on one addon enable there.

---

Some other references based on your comments here,

1. Mozila KB: [How to customize the toolbar](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/How+to+customize+the+toolbar)
2. HowToGeek: [Compact Your Menu Toolbar into a Single Button in Firefox](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4479/compact-your-menu-toolbar-into-a-single-button-in-firefox/)
3. [Get a cool sliding menu bar in Firefox](http://webmasterbyname.wordpress.com/2006/10/30/get-a-cool-sliding-menu-bar-in-firefox/)

   - based on LifeHacker article: [Geek to Live: Consolidate Firefox's chrome](http://lifehacker.com/software/firefox/geek-to-live--consolidate-firefoxs-chrome-210542.php)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been using so far, but I miss having the tab bar always on view. Plus I've got a lot of horizontal space available on my navigation bar.

Comment: Well, I moved some of my bookmarks to the navigation bar and eliminated the bookmarks bar altogether.

Comment: Good thing about the hot-key based hide is, you can quickly flip it on and off. You don't need the bar around when you are reading one of the tabs -- so, you don't miss anything.

Comment: Since I don't use any bookmarks, there's really a lot of empty space on my navigation bar. It's nice when I'm on a site with a really long URL, but most of the time it's just wasted space. If I can't find the extension I'm looking for, I'll definitely stick with "Hide tabbar".

Comment: You can move navigation (and also the search) to the menu-bar if you want. Just right-click in the empty space next to the menu items and select 'customize', then play around.

Answer (score 1):

[Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122/) has some nice Tab Bar options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it has the feature I'm looking for?

Comment: I'm reading your clarification now, and I'm not sure if this addon will exactly do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make the tab bar vertical rather than horrizontal.  Assuming I'm right, try this [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1343/).

Comment: No, I want to keep it horizontal. I want it to share the same vertical space as the navigation bar. That is, I want to be able to adjust its position, not change its orientation. I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my Notebook is not so large vertically and I use some techniques to navigate better saving more space in vertical.

1) Navigate with F11. So good. If you want to use another program, use alt+tab to change to it.

2) Reduce navigation toolbar icons. Right click on it, customize, small icons.

3) Hide or move (to menu bar) favorites toolbar. Right click on navigation toolbar and uncheck favorite toolbar if you want to hide it. If you want to move it to menu bar, right click on navigation toolbar, customize, then drag and drop favorite toolbar (the favorites) at end of menu bar; use a separator to do it better in appearence; then hide favorite toolbar (the bar).

4) Hide menu bar. Menu > Toolbars > uncheck Menu. To see it again, use alt.

5) Some pages have photos larger than navigator height. Then use alt+= or alt+- to adjust page size, or use Image Zoom addon to fit all pictures to navigation client screen.

Answer (score 0):

Classic Theme Restorer lets you move the URLbar and other navbar pieces into tabbar then disable navbar's "floor" of the browser.
To avoid ALT button triggering menubar, install All Menus Button and hide all menus from menubar. Hide titlebar. Now use CTR's single Firefox button as a menu. Or disable CTR's button and place the All Menus Button extension's single-menu button on the tabbar. This will make your Firefox extra slim.